# Stop executing a method when i click a button

Tags: java, android

How can i stop executing method when i click on a button??

I need a code that can stop executing codes in a specific method.
For example..

```
public class MainLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    final Button lbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonL);
    lbutton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ///there i need a code that stop the execution of myMethod()
                }
            }
    );

    myMethod();
    }

    public void myMethod() { /*all codes i want*/ }
```

Comment: What did you already tried ?

Comment: i tried to use system.exit(1); but this code stops and closes the application not only myMethod ()

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of a boolean flag.

For example you would have a boolean flag called "stopExecution" which by default is set to false. This flag is then set to "true" by your button click event.

In your method you can then check before every statement whether this flag is still set to false. If so, execute the statement. If however the flag is set to true you would call "return" (or "break" depending on whether a loop is being use) to return from the method and stop executing any more code.

If you have a for loop the following could be done:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(stopExecution){
        break;
    }else{
        //execute statement
    }
}
```